# preseed late_command script: realm could not connect to system bus

Tags: 18.04, preseed

I use the following preseed :

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    in-target wget http://my.server.adress.com/postinst.sh -O /root/postinst.sh; \
    in-target /bin/bash /root/postinst.sh
```

And in the script, at the end of it, I do :

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
set timeout 10
spawn realm join --user=usertojoinad mydomain.com
expect "Password for usertojoinad:"
send "TheJoinAdPassword\r";
expect eof
EOF
```

All other commands in postinst.sh are executed correctly, but for this command I get :

```
realm: Couldn't connect to system bus: Could no connect: No such file or directory". Sadly it does not say which file
```

This exact same command works if I type it in a terminal in the newly installed desktop after I login and `sudo su -`.

ppf on #ubuntu at freenode suggested that the user has no session, therefore dbus is not available. He proposed to try : `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID" DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"` . Yet this does not solve the issue.

Any hint on this ?

Edit: I tried to `sudo su -l -c` but it does not seem to solve this issue. When doing the `sudo su -l` I get : `pan_systemd(su:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I could do what I want by creating a service which run last. This is probably not the best way to do it, so I'd still like to solve this issue. In the meantime, here is how I did it :

in postinst.sh :

```
pam-auth-update --package --enable mkhomedir
wget --quiet http://my.server.adress.com/join_ad.sh -O /root/join_ad.sh
wget --quiet http://my.server.adress.com/firstbootsetup.sh -O /root/firstbootsetup.sh
chmod 760 /root/join_ad.sh
chmod 760 /root/firstbootsetup.sh
touch /root/firstboot.flag
wget --quiet http://my.server.adress.com/firstbootsetup.service.rename.txt -O /etc/systemd/system/firstbootsetup.service
systemctl enable firstbootsetup.service
```

in firstbootsetup.service.rename.txt :

```
[Unit]
Description=FirstBootSetup
ConditionPathExists=/root/firstboot.flag

[Service]
Type=idle
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/root/firstbootsetup.sh
ExecStartPost=/bin/rm -f /root/firstboot.flag

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

in firstbootsetup.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

/root/join_ad.sh
rm -f /root/join_ad.sh
```

in join_ad.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

realm discover mydomain.com

/usr/bin/expect << EOF
set timeout 10
spawn realm join --user=usertojoinad mydomain.com
expect "Password for usertojoinad:"
send "TheJoinAdPassword\r";
expect eof
EOF
```

Note: I started with this post https://serverfault.com/questions/853396/run-script-on-first-boot

Answer (score 0):

use option --install=/ in script
4ex:

```
#!/bin/bash

realm discover mydomain.com

/usr/bin/expect << EOF
set timeout 10
spawn realm join --install=/ --user=usertojoinad mydomain.com
expect "Password for usertojoinad:"
send "TheJoinAdPassword\r";
expect eof
EOF
```